# Struggling with Apache .htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently redoing one of my sites in Wordpress. This installation is currently sitting in wwww.mydomain.com/wordpress while I test it.

On my main site requests come in as so:
http://www.mydomain.com/index/newsid/16589/some-text-here-that-is-irrelevant

The .htaccess at http://www.mydomain.com/.htaccess currently looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule index/newsid/(.*) index.php?newsid=$1
RewriteEngine On
```

My Wordpress .htaccess currently sitting at www.mydomain.com/wordpress/.htaccess is as follows

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When I migrate my site all links from other sites are going to break, I have incorporated all the articles elsewhere in an archive in a forum. I need to effectively do two things, make my .htaccess work on the root of my site for wordpress after moving it AND redirect any newsid requests elsewhere.

Essentially I want to turn this:
http://www.mydomain.com/index/newsid/16589/some-text-here-that-is-irrelevant

Into:
http://www.mydomain.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=16589

They primary id here is 16589 which is a variable and can change.

Any help would be appreciated, I can do simple .htaccess files but this is beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add some rules *before* your wordpress rules after you've moved your wordpress installation to your document root. You'd need to do something like this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect your newsid
RewriteRule ^index/newsid/([0-9]+)/ /forums/index.php?showtopic=$1 [L,QSA,R]

# here are the wordpress rules

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

If you want 301 redirects instead, replace the `[L,QSA,R]` with `[L,QSA,R=301]`.